# To suppress or not to suppress (deprecation warning)?

Tags: android-studio, warnings, deprecated, lint

I have the following code in Android Studio Dolphin:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
     powerManager.isScreenOn();
} else {
     powerManager.isInteractive();
}
```

When I run `Code > Inspect code...` I see warning messages:

```
warning: [deprecation] isScreenOn() in PowerManager has been deprecated
```

But if I add

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
```

I then see the warning

```
Redundant suppression
```

which obviously is.

So, no matter what I do, I see warning messages...

Comment: Bug still present in 2023 (Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1)